# Use temp table or table variable for stored procedure that returns 100+ rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, temp-tables, coldfusion-8

Okay basically I am creating a stored procedure that will return data for our coldfusion power search.

I created a view, to hold data from multiple tables, with the same column names returned of course.

Then in my stored procedure i have created a simple temporary table like this....

```
    CREATE TABLE #TempSearchResults
(
    search_id int identity,
    id integer,
    type varchar(20),
    title varchar(50),
    url varchar(250),
    rank integer
)
```

Then I added an index to it, in my perhaps limited experience as a way to improve performance.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx on #TempSearchResults (search_id)
```

Then i did my select into massive query

```
insert into #TempSearchResults
select id, type, title, url, rank + 1200 as rank
from my view
where company_id = @company_id
and title like @keyword
union all
select id, type, title, url, rank + 1100 as rank
from my view
where company_id = @company_id
and title like @keyword
and description like @keyword
```

and it goes on like that having different rank math values for where it found the keyword in the tables.

And at the end it does...

```
select id, type, title, url, rank
from #TempSearchResults
group by id, type, title, url, rank
order by rank desc, title asc;
```

Now when I test that stored procedure in coldfusion, it seems to take very long.

So I am thinking, either I am using temp tables wrong or incompletely for optimal performance.

Or perhaps I should switch to table variables...

But I was just reading...[Temp Tables VS Table Variables](http://sqlnerd.blogspot.com/2005/09/temp-tables-vs-table-variables.html)

Funny thing is, this stored procedure seems to be slower than me running the query directly via coldfusion, which I prefer not to.

I am hoping for optimal performance....

Thank you...

Below is the basic logic or code for the view I am using.

```
select some field as id, some field as title, some field as description, 'url link' as url, 1 as rank
from table a
union
select some field as id, some field as title, some field as description, 'url link' as url, 1 as rank
from table b
union
select some field as id, some field as title, some field as description, 'url link' as url, 1 as rank
from table c
```

Etc like that. I can't reveal the exact details, as that would be a security breach. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: How long does your insert statement take to run? I bet that's the slow part... run it alone as a select and see how much of the time is spent there. Gotta figure out WHAT we need to optimize first!

Comment: When running the cfstoredproc in coldfusion it says 5312 ms. In SSMS it says total execution time 171.00

Comment: Can you give more information about the view.

Comment: The view itself, is a group of select against different tables in a union. This is to make it easier for me to search the same set of tables in many different ways, and makes it easier to read. One question, there is no dba at my company, just me and another programmer and our boss. Would it help if i ran UPDATE STATISTICS against the tables being used in the views/procedures?

Comment: I added more details about the view, at least in terms of basic logic flow.

Comment: Why are you using UNION in the view and not UNION ALL, when you are removing duplicates in the final select anyway ?

Comment: Because I didn't know that ahead of time. I had to craft the final sql, and make sure the results delivered exactly as my manager wanted, once all that is done, then I can re-edit the view, and procedure...But you made a very good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no need to use a temporary table or table variable at all. You can just write

```
select id, type, title, url, rank
from (
    select id, type, title, url, rank + 1200 as rank 
    from my view 
    where company_id = @company_id and title like @keyword 

    union all 

    select id, type, title, url, rank + 1100 as rank 
    from my view 
    where company_id = @company_id and title like @keyword and description like @keyword
) as t
group by id, type, title, url, rank
order by rank desc, title asc;
```

**Edit:**

Replacing UNION ALL by UNION, this can be simplified to

```
select id, type, title, url, rank + 1200 as rank 
from my view 
where company_id = @company_id and title like @keyword 

union 

select id, type, title, url, rank + 1100 as rank 
from my view 
where company_id = @company_id and title like @keyword and description like @keyword

order by rank desc, title asc;
```

Comment: I am familiar with this approach, is this better performance than temp table?

Comment: I would bet it is, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: Executing the changes in coldfusion, it is 5265ms. I had originally changed from union to union all, because union is more performance hog because it distincts the results.

Comment: Changing from union all to union made the coldfusion performance into 5515 ms.

Comment: If you know, that you have no duplicates, you can use UNION ALL and go without the group by. That outer group by is equivalent to a distinct in the outer select.

Comment: I know for a fact, that I will have duplicates, because I am search the same tables, in different ways, and having a different rank value for where the result was found. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Very nice and useful answer. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `with (Nolock)` hint on tables where ever you are selecting the data; it may improve performance if your application allows for dirty reads.